# Как делать сброс select по событию на чистом js?

Tags: javascript, html

Имеются textarea и select. Мне нужно по событию paste в textarea сбрасывать select. Как это сделать? По умолчанию `<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>`.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('textarea');
const select = document.querySelector('select');
text.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
  [...select.options].forEach((el, index) => {
    if(+el.value === 0) {
      select.selectedIndex = index;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<select>
  <option>-2</option>
  <option>-1</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt_in.addEventListener('paste', function(){    
    for (var i = 0, l = selectMenu.length; i < l; i++) {
        selectMenu[i].selected = selectMenu[i].defaultSelected;
    }
}
```

Comment: можно проще select.selectedIndex = 0;

Comment: Код выше срабатывает. Но появляется другой вопрос. Выше у меня есть другой код:

`selectMenu.addEventListener('change', function(){
 document.querySelector('#warning').style.display = (selectMenu.options[changeTime.selectedIndex].value == 0) ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
})`
Здесь появляется значок, который показывает select отличен от нуля. И когда срабатывает событие paste, select обнуляется, а значок остается. Как это исправить?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос,у вас вопрос Как делать сброс select по событию на чистом js?

Comment: @Александр, в selectMenu есть цифры от -6 до +6. И по событию должно возвращаться в '0'. select.selectedIndex = 0; не работает